# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)" Error in delete function

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Each task has a reference to the goal it is assigned to.  When I try and delete the tasks, and then the goal I get the error

"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries." on the line _goalRepository.Delete(goalId);

What am I doing wrong?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void DeleteGoal(int goalId, bool deleteTasks)
    {
        try
        {
            if (deleteTasks)
            {
                Goal goalWithTasks = _goalRepository.GetWithTasks(goalId);

                foreach (var task in goalWithTasks.Tasks)
                {
                    _taskRepository.Delete(task.Id);
                }
                goalWithTasks.Tasks = null;
                _goalRepository.Update(goalWithTasks);

            }

            _goalRepository.Delete(goalId);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception deleteException = ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're reusing the context via a field member, is that correct?

Comment: If you search the web for that error message, articles mention a concurrency issue with the data you are trying to update, that is, it is stale data. Sometimes the same exception is produced by different causes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is because you're attempting to hold onto and reuse a context across page views.  You should create a new context, do your work, and dispose of the context atomically.  It's called the Unit Of Work pattern.

The main reason for this is that the context maintains some state information about the database rows it has seen, if that state information becomes stale or out of date then you get exceptions like this.

There are a lot of other reasons to use the Unit of Work pattern, I would suggest you do a web search and do a little reading as an educational exercise.

Comment: Re "Most likely the problem is because you're attempting to hold onto and reuse a context across page views." I don't see any evidence for that?

Comment: @RobKent I asked the question in the comments and the OP responded that he was.

Comment: Yes, but the field member would be initialized each request, if he is using constructor injection or creating it manually in the constructor. Nothing he has said or shown indicates a static variable stored across requests. In fact, a field member would be destroyed along with the class; a static would be used by every thread, so it seems unlikely.

Comment: I disagree, I asked specifically, "you're reusing the context" and he answered in the affirmative.  Also, based on the exception that he's getting that's the logical conclusion.  But let's assume he's doing as you indicated, using a pattern of construction, work, destruction is arguably a better and less error prone pattern.

Comment: What does "reusing the context via a field member" mean though? A field member is per-request unless it is a static OR it is stored in the Session items collection and retrieved. The fact that he agreed that it is stored in a field member and reused in the class (during the same request) does not at all imply what you suggest, "across page views". He would have to be using a static or a Session variable for that. So your question was ambiguous. Where is he? :)

Answer (score 1):

This may have nothing to do with data access though. You are removing items from a list as you are iterating it, which would cause problems if you were using a normal List. Without knowing much about the internals of EF, my guess is that your delete calls to the repository are changing the same list that you are iterating.

Try iterating the list in one pass and record the Task ids you want to delete in separate list. Then when you have finished iterating, call delete on the Task list. For example:

```
var tasksToDelete = new List<int>();
foreach (var task in goalWithTasks.Tasks)
{
    tasksToDelete.Add(task.Id);
}

foreach (var id in tasksToDelete)
{
    _taskRepository.Delete(id);
}
```

This may not be the cause of your problem but it is good practice to never change the collection you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue at work (I am an Intern), I was getting this error when trying to delete a piece of Equipment that was referenced in other data-tables.

I was deleting all references before attempting to delete the Equipment BUT the reference deletion was happening in another Model which had its own database context, the reference deletion would be saved within the Model's context. 
But the Equipment Model's context would not know about the changes that just happened in another Model's context which is why when I was trying to delete the Equipment and then save the changes (eg: db.SaveChanges()) the error would happen (the Equipment context still thought there was references to that equipment in other tables).

My solution for this was to re-allocate the context before attempting to delete the Equipment:

db = new DatabaseContext();

Now the newly allocated context has the latest snapshot of the database and is aware of all changes made. Deletion happens without issues.

Hope my experience helps.